# Python outputting contents from file

Tags: python

When I'm running the program it is outputting that no countries exist starting with that letter, when in fact they exist. Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong or maybe give me an alternate way to only output countries starting with the wanted letter. This is my code:

```
#Creating the list
CountryList = []
CountryandPopulationList = []
#Creating the Function1
def Function1(fh,letter):
    count = 0
    #Adding the file to the list
    for word in fh:
        CountryandPopulationList.append(word)
        index = word.find('-')
        Country = word[0:index]
        CountryList.append(Country.strip()) 

    #Printing countries starting with chosen letter
    try:
        for i in CountryList:
            if(i[1]== letter):
                print(i)
                count = count + 1
            else:
                print('The letter does not exist')
    except IndexError:
        print('Total number of countries starting with letter',letter,'=',count )

#Asking user to input letter
letter = input('Enter the first letter of the country: ')

#Opening the file 
try:
    fh = open('D:\FOS\\Countries.txt','r')
except IOError:
    print('File does not exist')
else:
    function1 = Function1(fh,letter)
```

Thank you

Comment: Isn't the first letter `i[0]`?

Comment: No because there is a space before

Comment: Could you add example input and expected output?

Comment: Maybe, in your input list. But `Country.strip())` removes them!

Comment: This is the output I'm getting :Enter the first letter of the country: M
The letter does not exist
Total number of countries starting with letter M = 0

Comment: I tried without the Country.strip() and still the same output

Comment: Answering without knowing the contents of the Countries.txt is pure guessing. You would get much better answers if you would provide the file (or shortened sample) that reproduces the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please also provide the input format of your Countries.txt file as well as the python version you are using s.t. it is easier to help you.

For a start: open() will not provide you with the file content but only gives you the textwrapper object. Try changing the line to

```
fh = open('D:\FOS\...\Countries.txt', 'r').read()
```

Comment: The version is 3.6 and this is part of the file Countries.txt :China - 1382323332
India - 1326801576
U.S. - 324118787
Indonesia - 260581100
Brazil - 209567920
Pakistan - 192826502
Nigeria - 186987563
Bangladesh - 162910864
Russia - 143439832
Mexico - 128632004
Japan - 126323715
Philippines - 102250133
Ethiopia - 101853268
Viet Nam - 94444200
Egypt - 93383574
Germany - 80682351
Iran - 80043146
DR Congo - 79722624

Comment: @AngeleAquilina, is each country in a different line? or is everything in a single line?

Comment: The weird thing is when I use CountryandPopulationList instead of the CountryList the countries are printing correctly.

Comment: @AngeleAquilina That's probably because `strip` removes the whitespace before the items in `CountryList`. It would help if you could add the example to the question so that it could be directly copied to the text editor. If you copy from above comment it will all be on a single line which probably wasn't the original format.

Comment: Each country is in a single line  @Seba

Comment: @niemmi I removed the strip() and yes each country is in single line.

Comment: Thanks all for trying to help me :)

Answer (score 0):

A slightly simpler version. Try this:

```
def function1(fh, letter):
    count = 0
    country_list = [line.split('-')[0].strip() for line in fh.readlines()]

    for country in country_list:
        if country.lower().startswith(letter.lower()):
            count += 1
            print(country)
    print("Total number of countries starting with letter '%s'= %d" % (letter, count))


#Asking user to input letter
letter = input('Enter the first letter of the country: ')

#Opening the file
try:
    with open('D:\FOS\\Countries.txt','r') as fh:
        function1(fh, letter)
except IOError:
    print('File does not exist')
```

Comment: Thanks a lot but as I have to do this for school I have to use things that are in the syllabus and we never did anything like this : country_list = [line.split('-')[0].strip() for line in fh.readlines()]. But thanks appreciate it :)

Comment: in that case, your code seems to be fine, just change "for word in fh:" to "for word in fh.readlines():"